# Completed 200 OK in 652ms (Views: 50.9ms | ActiveRecord: 18.3ms)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to understand this line in the rails log

If my views only took 50.9ms why is it taking 652ms?

Thanks

Comment: Just answered something very similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491663/rails-completed-time-for-a-request-significantly-higher-than-view-and-db-times/7493103

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're running your application in the development environment it has to reload a lot of your application's files on every request.  That would be my guess as to why it's taking so long.

You could try going into `environments/development.rb` and setting `config.cache_classes = true` to see what kind of effect this has on your render times, but remember to change this back to `config.cache_classes = false` and restart your server once you're done.

Comment: what abot when it happens in production? what could the difference come from?